# Fast Scroll Always Visible property disables background

Tags: android

I have a fast scroll which shows a 'preview letter' or 'bubble'  when you are swiping the thumb along the track in the scroll. This is my styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/bar</item>
<item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">atThumb</item>
```

I want to make always visible this fast scroll, so I set the following style to make it visible:

```
<item name="android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible">true</item>
```

The problem is after setting that true now the bubble is not displayed anymore.
How can I make visible the fastScroll but still displaying that bubble?